# Windows File System over HTTP

Tags: windows, filesystems, http

It looks like you can mount a one drive folder, see: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/34847-onedrive-map-onedrive-pc-windows-8-1-a.html

Question is what kind of file system is this? How can I implement an http based file system that would be compatible with Windows (preferably in c#)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that it is just WEBDAV.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV
- http://www.webdav.org/